# Handlebars - inline decode context and fill the template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a json which contains JSON but encoded.
Data field in container 2 is a string. I want to use this data and other fields in the JSON to populate the template.

```
var data = {
      "containers": [
        {
          "containerId": 1,
          "containerLabel": "1",
          "dataType": "URL",
          "data": "http://www.google1.com",
          "dataEncoding": null,
          "startDTS": "2019-04-03T10:41:04.570Z",
          "endDTS": "2025-01-01T18:29:59.999Z",
          "containerAnalyticsData": {
            "variationId": "563601179",
            "actionBlockId": "29408_563601179ActionBlock_0",
            "campaignId": 29408,
            "containerId": "1",
            "controlGroupId": "23517",
            "treatmentId": "8f3b53a9-1a7e-4fbe-b28f-450fa88ab474"
          }
        },
        {
          "containerId": 2,
          "containerLabel": "2",
          "dataType": "application/json",
                  "data": "{\"cardType\":\"123Stock\",\"cardTypeID\":5,\"cardID\":\"/content/help/en/ccx/v1/stock/width/2/stock-search\",\"cardName\":\"123 Stock\",\"displayTemplate\":\"123Stock\",\"width\":2,\"backgroundImage\":\"https://helpx.123.com/content/dam/help/en/ccx/stock/stock-june2017-2w-730x280.jpg\",\"backgroundFillColor\":\"\",\"invertPresentation\":false,\"overlayTintColor\":\"\",\"overlayTintPercentage\":0.0,\"priority\":1,\"cardLabel\":\"GET TEN FREE IMAGES FROM 123 STOCK\",\"displayText\":\"Get 10 free 123 Stock images.\",\"displayTextAlignment\":\"center\",\"bodyCopy\":\"\",\"bodyCopyAlignment\":\"left\",\"ctaLabel\":\"Go\",\"ctaAlignment\":\"right\",\"secondaryCTALabel\":\"\",\"secondaryCTAAlignment\":\"right\",\"actionURL\":\"https://stock.123.com/search?k=\",\"urlLinkType\":\"external\",\"defaultURL\":\"https://stock.123.com\",\"urlAppendAnalyticsParams\":true,\"urlApply123Authentication\":true,\"footnote\":\"\",\"searchLabel\":\"\"}",
          "dataEncoding": null,
          "startDTS": "2019-04-03T10:41:04.493Z",
          "endDTS": "2025-01-02T07:59:59.999Z",
          "containerAnalyticsData": {
            "variationId": "563597567",
            "actionBlockId": "28018_563597567ActionBlock_0",
            "campaignId": 28018,
            "containerId": "2",
            "controlGroupId": "",
            "treatmentId": "PR-91a1350b-1f86-46f4-8193-0e06fbc9412d"
          }
        }]
    };
```

Is there a way to decode this data inline and populate the template?

Here is the fiddle link which has the logic to populate the template: http://jsfiddle.net/agoyal/38goqau5/6/

**EDIT:**
The resulting object should have the inner data element in JSON instead of string.

I am almost there. I want to build my own object, but there is a small issue that i have to use data.data now instead of just data. How can i return the whole object by modifying the current context?
 See this fiddle : [jsfiddle.net/agoyal/0fwm768n/29](http://jsfiddle.net/agoyal/0fwm768n/29)

Comment: You can [register a helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) function (say, parse) for the `data` field which can take its value and parse it into a JSON and then transform that JSON into a proper HTML that you return as output.

You'd use `{{{parse data}}}` for it then.

Comment: You can also transform the value of the `data` field in all objects (such that it is proper JSON) prior to passing the values to the Handlebars for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to make a helper that parses you string to JSON.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6proe0wn/)

```
<div>
   {{data.cardID}}
</div>


Handlebars.registerHelper('eachJson', function(context, options) {
    let returnValue = ""

  $.each(context, function() {
    if (this.dataType === "application/json") {
      const json = JSON.parse(this.data)

      returnValue += options.fn({
        //Return the whole JSON
        data: json
      });      
    } else {
        returnValue += options.fn({
                data: this.data
      })
    }
  })

    return returnValue;

})
```

**EDIT:**

Comment: This is a good try, but it looses the original context, i.e. JSON with parent element key 'data'.

Comment: But you can not output a JSON object as HTML. Ether you build your new object in the return of the helper or you can return the whole JSON and pick you the data you want in the HTML. Check my edit...

Comment: I am almost there. I want to build my own object, but there is a little issue that i have to use data.data now instead of just data.
How can i return the whole object by modifying the current context?

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/agoyal/0fwm768n/29/

Comment: You can always change the property of the new data to value, and the you get value.data instead if that feels better.

Comment: So, there is no inline way of changing current context, but the only solution is to make a new object?